# Working on workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

This may be a very basic question. Is working on workbench and using the sql query offline mode, the black one(sorry for the language but just a newbie) same or are they different?

Also is working on workbench easy or require some prior knowledge? I tried to download the normal sql parts but they were just giving problems so decided to install just the workbench and do my work on that. Is it one and the same? Will i get some problems later on if i use just the workbench?

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using the workbench for executing the scripts. This will work same as the sql server. you can refer the basic sql scripts throught this site.

[Basic Scripts](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/)